# Django Rest custom serialize field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My models.py is as follows:

```
class CoinSetting(models.Model):
coin = models.ForeignKey(Coin, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
TYPES = (
        (0, "Amount"),
        (1, "Share"),
        )

    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=0)
    type_value = models.FloatField()
```

and I want to serialize it to looks like that:

```
"coins": [
        {
          "coin": ....
          "setting": {
            "Amount": 10.1
          }
        }
    ]
```

User can choose the form of sharing coin, i.e some amount of coin or percentage of some amount. Field "type" describe the form that user can choose, and field "type_value" is for insert this value (amount or percentage) to the chosen type. So:

- for "Amount", the value is some integer (float field),
- for "Share", the value is integer from 0 to 1 (this is percentage of amount, float field in range (0, 1)).

How can I serialize that model to get that display?

Comment: Hi! Please share your problem statement. From what I can see, you might need a Amount field in your model as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.